# Quadratic matrices: When is $A^\top B^\top = AB$?

Tags: matrices

When is $A^\top B^\top = AB$ true?

Context: I saw this as $AB=BA \implies (AB)^\top=(BA)^\top=A^\top B^\top=AB$.

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ and $B$ commute *and* are both symmetric?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm assuming.

Comment: Well, that certainly suffices. I do not know necessary conditions — certainly you would need to be more explicit with quantifiers.

Comment: Yeah, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and commute.

$$(AB)^\top\underset{\text{commute}}{=}(BA)^\top\underset{\text{Prop. of }^\top}{=}A^\top B^\top\underset{\text{symmetric}}{=}AB$$

(Thanks, Ted Shifrin)